# Can I put ferrite cores around the romex in my electrical boxes and breaker panel?

Tags: circuit-breaker, ferrite, ferrite-bead, arc, gfci

I've recently replaced most of the breakers in my house with dual-function arc fault/ground fault protection. (I spent five years in forensics, I'm deeply paranoid, don't judge me.) Naturally I'm seeing a few more random trips than I used to. I suspect some are related to motor turn-off inductive kicks, and others are perhaps related to coupled noise from a subwoofer.

In any case, I think in principle I should be able to mitigate these effects with ferrite cores. A ferrite core around a power cable should increase common-mode impedance, and thus resist ground fault currents. (It may also help with spurious arc fault detection, but I'm a little fuzzier on that theory.) Now, in principle I should be able to install such cores in electrical boxes or breaker panels, as long as they go around the entire Romex and not just the hot line.

Is there anything wrong with my theory? Is what I'm suggesting code-compliant? Are there any problems I haven't foreseen? Is this a thing that has a history of being done?

Comment: Go monitor an electrician's forum sometime.  Notice how many gripes they have about nuisance trips (especially for older tech arc fault/ground fault breakers).  About your ferrites: If adding them actually did what you want them to do, then you are affecting the response of the devices in some unknown way.  How many pounds of ferrite around your wires is enough?  **How will you know if it's too much?** Me thinks your question is unanswerable, unless someone can simply say: "There's no point in doing this; adding ferrite will have no effect on your issue."

Comment: Ferrite won't do anything to a disruption lasting more than a couple microseconds, whilst GFCI already ignore anything quicker than a dozen or two milliseconds; you would need thousands of cores to have a measurable effect.

Comment: The real question is we'll electrical code allow for this in the country you live in. Electrical code is not really on topic here